# incompatible transaction problem

Tags: go-ethereum

My private network is not EIP155 enabled. It does runs the latest version of geth, but the blockchain has EIP155 field set to `nil` .

I used MyEtherWallet and submitted a EIP155 transaction (to test what happens) and now this transaction is stuck:

```
> eth.getTransaction("0x31189dbbe5fbd5fcb779889f0c31c670a2ccbabcfdd94c130d9ac9f32e526af4")
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x7b5576dfeb32429899732a4183ea106407899a68",
  gas: 100000,
  gasPrice: 32000000000,
  hash: "0x31189dbbe5fbd5fcb779889f0c31c670a2ccbabcfdd94c130d9ac9f32e526af4",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 1,
  r: "0xaf51eeec11f04fbb1801ebf00945ab770c511d8c7531ecde6b460cbfde381328",
  s: "0x251b0b1be78600de8ff8604eb5b4809091341a67819d5534c86221a5da8860ca",
  to: "0x73a0e252e5114c21d5e601fcb7f3b6e341da29fd",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1f6",
  value: 990000000000000000
}
>
```

I submitted it yesterday, 20 hours have passed but it still pending. The network isn't busy , so there is no problem with gas limits, also I increased the gas on purpose. So, what is going to happen now, will this transaction be there forever? How could I remove it? And why it was accepted in the first place, why didn't the node reject it?

Comment: Is mining enabled?

Comment: @LSong on the node that I have submitted it mining is disabled. But it has propagated to the other nodes already and one of this nodes has mining enabled, but it doesn't have the computing power to mine a block. The nodes that have computing power are out of my control, but they should have my transaction in pending list too, I guess

Comment: It is my understanding that some valid transactions after EIP 155 (those that use v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35 or 36) are not valid before it is activated, and will never get mined.

Comment: @Ismael , so, this means, that now, I will never get money from this account? The account has been locked forever ?

Comment: @Nulik If you send a transaction with the same nonce and higher gas price it should have priority over your previous transaction. Just be sure it is a valid transaction before EIP 155, ie v = 27 or v = 28.